# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running lein command to instal leiningen

Tags: java, shell, leiningen

While running `lein` in the shell, the console output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.core$fn__8478.invokeStatic(core.clj:7060)
    at clojure.core$fn__8478.invoke(core.clj:7055)
    at clojure.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-internal/Class.java:378)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2207)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2216)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2235)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:471)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:338)
    at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method:java.lang.reflect.Method.canAccess(Object)boolean/invokeVirtual
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(java.base@9-    internal/MemberName.java:929)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(java.base@9-internal/MemberName.java:1046)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(java.base@9-internal/MethodHandles.java:1683)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(java.base@9-internal/MethodHandles.java:939)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.<clinit>(Reflector.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:java.lang.reflect.Method.canAccess(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(java.base@9-internal/MemberName.java:1018)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(java.base@9-internal/MemberName.java:1043)
    ... 17 more
```

I am unable to apply the solution proposed on the thread 
[cannot run lein script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134766/cannot-run-lein-script).
The command `lein version` output the same.

Using ubuntu 16.04

`update-java-alternatives -l` output:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64       1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64
```

`java -version` output:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

`$PATH` output :

```
/home/camello/bin:/home/camello/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Actually trying to install Lighttable editor...lol

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `openjdk version "9-internal"`

You have to install the default JRE/JDK.

Purge/remove previous JRE/JDK installation.
Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, install Java. Specifically, this command will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE):

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

You can install the JDK with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Command `java -version` should output something like that:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

That's all.